# Pagination In Django With Postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman, backend

I am using Django version 2.1 and I am testing my project using Postman.
This is my views.py file :-

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView,RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny


# Add + List
# Retrieve Update Destroy
# List: Pagination

class ShowAddaView(ListCreateAPIView):

    from .serializers import AddAddaSerializer

    from .models import Adda

    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    serializer_class = AddAddaSerializer
    queryset = Adda.objects.all()


class RetrieveAddaView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    from .serializers import AddAddaSerializer

    from .models import Adda

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = AddAddaSerializer
    queryset = Adda.objects.all()
```

I am applying GET and POST method in postman. My serializer file looks like this :

```
class AddAddaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        from .models import Adda
        model = Adda
        fields = '__all__'


class UpdateAddaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    mobile = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        from .models import Adda
        model = Adda
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now I need to access my data using the GET method in Postman with pagination. 
Can anyone tell me what changes I need to do to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this settings to your `settings.py` file,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10  # Change this value according to your need
}
```

or You could add pagination class in View level by **`pagination_class`** as

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


class ShowAddaView(ListCreateAPIView):
    # your code
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination


class RetrieveAddaView(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    # your code
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
```

For more details, refer [Pagination in DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)